# filtering input form over type using d3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am trying to select all the button in an html form in order to add some onclick event, but I still have a 'd' undefined error, can someone explain me where I'm wrong ?

here the html code :

```
<Form id="menu_f">
<input type="file"   id="import_f"  value="data.json" class="__KR_VIEW">
<input type="button" id="import"    value="Import Data"  class="__KR_VIEW">
<input type="button" id="edit_kr"   value="Edit KR"  class="__KR_VIEW" >
....(a lot of input)
</form>
```

here the d3 code :

```
d3.select("#menu_f").selectAll("input").filter(function(d){return d.attr("type") == "button"}).on("click",function(d){menuHandler(d.attr("id"))});
```

here is the error I get :

```
TypeError: d is undefined
```

thank you !

Comment: The d represents data that you've "attached" to that element/node, as you're using the d3.filter() method.

You probably want to use the native Array.filter() on the dom elements

Comment: Thank you, it is working, I was thinking that the d stands for all the elements in the selection !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/kmzjjtyj/

The d represents data that you've "attached" to that element/node, as you're using the d3.filter() method.

You probably want to use the native Array.filter() on the dom elements, by stepping into the d3 collection.

Eg.

```
 d3
.select("#menu_f")
.selectAll("input")[0] // Step into the d3 collection to reach the array of elements
.filter(function(d) {
   // Filter on the array of elements
});
```

Comment: Thank you again for this detailled answer !
problem solved !

Answer (score 2):

While @AdamBotley's answer is correct, the more `d3`ish way to do this is:

```
d3.select("#menu_f")
  .selectAll("input")
  .filter(function(d) {
    return (this.type === "button");
  })
  ...
```

In a `d3` function, `this` most always refers to the selected element.

---

Full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="menu_f">
    <input type="file" id="import_f" value="data.json" class="__KR_VIEW" />
    <input type="button" id="import" value="Import Data" class="__KR_VIEW" />
    <input type="button" id="edit_kr" value="Edit KR" class="__KR_VIEW" />
  </form>
  <script>
    d3.select("#menu_f")
    .selectAll("input")
    .filter(function(d) {
      return (this.type === "button");
    }).each(function(d){
      console.log(this);
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `return this.type == "button";` should be enough in your filter

Comment: @nikoshr, thanks, good catch.  I might be too used to doing things the `d3` way :)